# Mystery of the If() function in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I have this code:

```
dstCell.CELL_VALUE_INT = If(srcCell.CELL_VALUE_FLOAT IsNot Nothing,
                            Math.Round(CDbl(srcCell.CELL_VALUE_FLOAT)),
                            Nothing)
```

when **srcCell.CELL_VALUE_FLOAT is Nothing** it mysteriously evaluates to the True part!

Funny part is that a normal If statement correctly evaluates to the False part:

```
If (srcCell.CELL_VALUE_FLOAT IsNot Nothing) Then
    dstCell.CELL_VALUE_INT = Math.Round(CDbl(srcCell.CELL_VALUE_FLOAT))
Else
    dstCell.CELL_VALUE_INT = Nothing
End If
```

Any ideas?

Thank u!

EDIT:
CELL_VALUE_FLOAT is a Nullable(Of Double) and CELL_VALUE_INT is a Nullable(of Integer)

In Quickwatch the condition evaluates correclty to False, but when running the If() function evaluates to the True part.

Comment: Can you replace `srcCell.CELL_VALUE_UOM` with a real value for us, is it a string?

Comment: Your example is wrong. In the first statement you evaluate CELL_VALUE_FLOAT, in the second test you evaluate CELL_VALUE_UOM. I suspect that CELL_VALUE_FLOAT is never nothing.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to replace a part writing the question here on StackOverflow. Now I corrected it. As stated below, my CELL_VALUE_FLOAT is a Nullable(Of Double) so its value can be Nothing. In quickwatch the condition corrrectly evaluate to False, but when running, it evaluates the True part!

Comment: Actually, **`If()` is not a function**; It's an [operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/if-operator). All function parameters are fully evaluated before the call. By design and to good effect, `If()` doesn't work that way.

Comment: Yes, that's the correct term. On the other hand, `IIf` is a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Nothing` in VB.NET is not fully equal to `null` in C#
It is more like `default(T)` where T is a Type.

```
' VB:
dim x as DateTime = DateTime.MinValue
If x Is Nothing then
    Console.WriteLine("True")
End if

' C#
var x = DateTime.MinValue
if (x == default(DateTime))
    Console.WriteLine("True");

if (x == null) ' throw a compile time error
```

And

```
dim x as Double = nothing ' x will be 0 (default for Double)
```

the build in inline if expects both return values to be the same type. So what you a really doing is:

```
dstCell.CELL_VALUE_INT = If(srcCell.CELL_VALUE_FLOAT IsNot Nothing,
                            Math.Round(CDbl(srcCell.CELL_VALUE_FLOAT)),
                            Convert.ToDouble(Nothing))
```

since the false part gets internally converted to double
and `dstCell.CELL_VALUE_INT` will be 0 instead of nothing.

Try this one:

```
dstCell.CELL_VALUE_INT = If(srcCell.CELL_VALUE_FLOAT IsNot Nothing,
                         Ctype(Math.Round(CDbl(srcCell.CELL_VALUE_FLOAT)), Integer?),
                         Nothing)
```

Comment: "the build in inline if expects both return values to be the same type." **That's probably the best explanation!**

Comment: Assuming option strict(what should be default for everybody): `dim x as DateTime = DateTime.MinValue
If x Is Nothing then` will also throw a compiler error since a `DateTime` is not a reference type.

Comment: `Assuming option strict(what should be default for everybody)` This is true and for new projects I would strongly recommend that. But we have a huge VB.NET project that we can't just change without huge modifications.

Answer (score 9):

> when srcCell.CELL_VALUE_FLOAT is Nothing it mysteriously evaluates to the True part!

Nope, it does not. It just evalues the false part (`Nothing`) as `0`, thus setting `CELL_VALUE_INT` to 0.

---

Let me elaborate: The expression

```
Dim i As Integer? = If(False, 1, Nothing)
```

fills `i` with `0`. (Test it, if you don't believe me.)

Why does this happen? `Nothing` in VB.NET is not the same as `null` in C#. If used with a value type, `Nothing` means "the default value of that type". `If` infers `Integer` (not `Integer?`) as the common type for `1` and `Nothing`, and, thus, evaluates `Nothing` as `default(Integer) = 0`.

You can fix this as follows:

```
Dim i As Integer? = If(False, 1, DirectCast(Nothing, Integer?))
```

which, in your example, would mean

```
dstCell.CELL_VALUE_INT = If(srcCell.CELL_VALUE_FLOAT IsNot Nothing,   
                            Math.Round(CDbl(srcCell.CELL_VALUE_FLOAT)),   
                            DirectCast(Nothing, Integer?))
```

This should yield the correct value now.

---

Since this is quite surprising behaviour, I have filed a [Microsoft Connect suggestion](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/496905/if-operator-not-returning-a-nullable-type) some time ago to add a compiler warning.

Comment: Hoping they will add a compile-time warning about this behavior!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your value is a [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xay7978z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)(Float):

The default value of `Single` is 0 not `Nothing`.

You can use a [`Nullable(Of T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) if you want to check for null values.

```
Dim srcCell.CELL_VALUE_FLOAT As Nullable(Of Single)
srcCell_CELL.VALUE_FLOAT = Nothing
Dim dstCell.CELL_VALUE_INT As Nullable(Of Int32) = _
    (If(srcCell.CELL_VALUE_FLOAT.HasValue,
        CInt(Math.Round(CDbl(srcCell.CELL_VALUE_FLOAT))),
        Nothing))
```

Comment: My CELL_VALUE_FLOAT is a Nullable(Of Double) so its value can be Nothing.
In quickwatch the condition corrrectly evaluate to False, but when running, it evaluates the True part!

Comment: I will try to use HasValue, instead of isNot Nothing. Thank u.

Comment: @Teejay: null comparison should also map to `HasValue`.

Comment: Still evaluates to 0.0 instead of Nothing :(